# What is the simplest way to parse this table:

Tags: c#, winforms

I have List that I want to display in my form. But first, I want to move all the non relevant part. This is my List:

```
===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter:

eth                                      frames:8753 bytes:6185473
  ip                                     frames:8753 bytes:6185473
    tcp                                  frames:8661 bytes:6166313
      http                               frames:1230 bytes:792126
        data-text-lines                  frames:114 bytes:82636
          tcp.segments                   frames:56 bytes:41270
        image-gif                        frames:174 bytes:109968
          tcp.segments                   frames:57 bytes:37479
        image-jfif                       frames:195 bytes:154407
          tcp.segments                   frames:185 bytes:142340
        png                              frames:35 bytes:30521
          tcp.segments                   frames:20 bytes:15770
        media                            frames:39 bytes:32514
          tcp.segments                   frames:32 bytes:24755
        tcp.segments                     frames:6 bytes:1801
        xml                              frames:5 bytes:3061
          tcp.segments                   frames:1 bytes:960
      ssl                                frames:20 bytes:14610
    udp                                  frames:92 bytes:19160
      dns                                frames:92 bytes:19160
===================================================================
```

I want to display the first column (protocol type) and in the second column only the part after "frames:" without bytes:xxxx

Answer (score 1):

Probably using Regex, something along the lines of:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(?<protocol>[ a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*)frames:(?<frameCount>[0-9]).*$");   
   foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(myListOfProtocolsAsAString))
   {
      if(match.Success)
      {
         string protocol = match.Groups[1].Value;
         int byteCount = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
      }
   }
```

Then you can access the matching groups (protocol & framecount) on the Match instance.

Comment: i received error in foreach command: "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"

Comment: @user979033: I think I've updated my answer since? either that or myListOfProtocolsAsAString is a List<String> rather than a String. If so then use a StringBuilder to combine them all up, or run the Regex over multiple times rgx.Match for each string, rather than the bulky way.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ever popular Linq to Objects

```
var lines = new string[]
  {
    "eth                                    frames:8753 bytes:6185473",
    "ip                                     frames:8753 bytes:6185473"
  };

var values = lines.Select(
    line=>line.Split(new string[]{"frames:", "bytes:"}, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .Select (items => new {Name=items[0].Trim(), Value=items[1].Trim()});
```